# Chatango Chaning Time

Tags: python, datetime

Running a `chatango` bot.
I'm trying to get the bot to print the:
`(in order) time, name, access level, body.`

Example:
`01:02:03 Jan 7th 2014 - YouColdYet(4): Something Something Something`

Current code:

```
def onMessage(self, room, user, message):
    print(user.name+":"+message.body)
    print("User Access Level: %s" % self.rank(user))
```

I don't like it multiple lines as it eats up space. The `self.rank` is from the access module so it works, it's just getting it to cooperate with the others to PRINT on the same line.

I was able to get it to work with the time module `asc` but it wouldn't count every message, just post the same time. So it looked like:

```
youcoldyet: whatever
User Access Level: 4
Current Time: Always the same
youcoldyet: something something
User Access Level: 4
Current Time: Always the same
```

All feedback is welcome.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Getting the time module, access rank, name, and message body on the same line. Plus a time that goes by %H %M %S %M %D %Y and changes with each print since asc won't(Sorry lots of typos from lag)
Also thanks for the edit Jerry! Much appreciated.

Comment: you want to print it all on one line?

Comment: Yes. I tried using `and` at one point, but then it sent me only the `self.rank(user)` response of (1,2,3,4) and NOTHING else. I even tried to use the default of `+` between each which broke it. Not sure how to proceed. And I can't have it on multiple lines as it eats space. Also trying to get it where the time CHANGES rather than says the same time OVER and OVER. All in a clean format.

Comment: have you tried putting a `,` after you print statement or string formatting?

Comment: It's not currently clear where the time is even coming from, so it's hard to help there. However you probably want to set up a template then [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) it. The time can be manipulated with [`strptime` and `strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham `print(user.name, time.time, self.rank(user)+":"+message.body)` i tried and ran that. Gave a error whenever something was said in the console. @jonrsharpe `t = time.localtime()` was the code I was using. I will check that out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is something like:

```
from datetime import datetime 

def on_message(self, room, user, message):
    template = "{0} - {1.name}({1.rank}): {2.body}"
    timetemp = "%H:%M:%S %b %d %Y"
    print(template.format(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), # or 'message.time'?
                                            timetemp), 
                          user, message))
```

A demo using dummy objects:

```
>>> class Dummy(object):
    pass

>>> user = Dummy()
>>> user.name = "YouColdYet"
>>> user.rank = 4
>>> message = Dummy()
>>> message.body = "Something Something Something"
>>> on_message(None, None, user, message)
10:53:48 Jul 03 2014 - YouColdYet(4): Something Something Something
```

Comment: Thank you! Partly did it, and the rest I figured with my friend!